# JSF: display h:selectManyCheckBox vertically in h:dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a simply facelet which display a list of products in tabular format. In the last column of each row, there is a checkbox used to mark the product for deletion. Until now i have to put a selectBooleanCheckBox on each row and have a "mark for deletion" property in the Product entity but i think it's ugly because i have some presentation stuff in my model bean.

Is there anyway to have a h:selectManyCheckBox which has its f:selectItem distribute on each row of the dataTable ?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`t:selectManyCheckbox layout="spread"`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_selectManyCheckbox.html) is an excellent suggestion.

As an alternative, you can also just bind the `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` component to a `Map<Long, Boolean>` property where `Long` represents the entity ID (or whatever identifier which you can use to identify the row) and `Boolean` represents the checked state.

E.g.

```
public class Bean {
    private List<Entity> entities;
    private Map<Long, Boolean> checked = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();

    public void submit() {
        for (Entity entity : entities) {
            if (checked.get(entity.getId())) {
                // Entity is checked. Do your thing here.
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

with

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.entities}" var="entity">
    <h:column>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.checked[entity.id]}" />
    </h:column>
    ...
</h:dataTable>
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
```

The `Map<Long, Boolean>` will be automagically filled with the ID of all entities as map keys and the checkbox value is set as map value associated with the entity ID as key.

#### See also:

- [Using datatables - Select multiple rows](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#SelectMultipleRows)

Answer (score 3):

You can, using MyFaces Tomahawk's [`<t:selectManyCheckbox>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_selectManyCheckbox.html) with `layout="spread"`

Answer (score 1):

In my application, i have used below set of code to get multiple checkbox list to be displayed vertically with scrollbar:

```
<style type="text/css">
#productCategoryId label {
  float: inherit;
  font-size: 10px!important;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#productCategoryId table.formTable th, table.formTable td {
  padding: 0px 0px 0 0;
}
</style>

<div style="width:200px;height: 280px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;border:1px solid #999;" max-height=280px>
             <h:selectManyCheckbox  id="productCategoryId" layout="pageDirection" style="width:200px" styleClass="changeId">
                  <f:selectItem itemValue="-1000" itemLabel="ALL" />
                  <f:selectItems value="#{lookup.list['RSM_LOOKUP']['PRODUCT_CATEGORY']}"/>
                </h:selectManyCheckbox >
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use selectManyCheckbox and dataTable is...

=== Page.xhtml ===

```
<ice:selectManyCheckbox id="idSelectManyCheckbox" layout="spread"
   value="#{MyBean.selectedsValuesCheckbox}" >
   <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.selectItemsCheck}"/>
</ice:selectManyCheckbox>

<ice:dataTable varStatus="rowVar"
   value="#{MyBean.listOfMyObjects}" var="anyNameVar">

   <ice:column>
      <ice:checkbox for="idSelectManyCheckbox" index="#{rowVar.index}" />
   </ice:column>
   <ice:column>
      <ice:outputText value="#{anyNameVar.property1}" />
   </ice:column>

   <!-- ... more columns .. -->
</ice:dataTable>
```

=== MyBean.java ===

```
private List<MyObject> listOfMyObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>(3);
private List<String> selectedsValuesCheckbox = new ArrayList<String>(2);
private SelectItem[] selectItemsCheck = new SelectItem[3];

private handleSelectItemsCheck(){
   int idx = 0;
   selectedsValuesCheckbox.add("1");
   selectedsValuesCheckbox.add("3");
   for (MyObject myObject : listOfMyObjects) {
      selectItemsCheck[idx++] = 
    new SelectItem(myObject.property1, myObject.property2); // value and label
   }
}
```

// Gets and sets

================================================================

```
*you must use layout="spread" in that situation.
*in the table the checkboxs 1 and 3 will be selected. because "selectedsValuesCheckbox"
```